# How to change image on panel when doing a mouseover - ExtJs?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I'm trying to change the image of **each panel** when doing a **mouseOver** and **mouseLeave**.

If I do **mouseover** on a panel (image), this image should be replaced by a new one (any image). For example the first panel that has the **HTML5** image should change to a new image, and if I do a **mouseleave** the HTML5 image should **show up again**. Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Here's the working code: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/henryDev/b67vu4Lk/3/)

```
    layout: {
    type: 'accordion',
    titleCollapse: false
     },
     items: [{
    title: '<i class="fa fa-html5" style="font-size:50px;color:black;" id="developmentIcon"></i>',
     xtype: 'panel-details'
     },{
     title: '<i  class="fa fa-wrench" style="font-size:50px;color:black;" id="developmentIcon"></i>',
    xtype: 'panel-details'
    }
     ....
     .....
```

NOTE:
I'm just using **font awesome** images for simplicity, but they can be any type of image such as .png, .svg, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`panel.getHeader().getEl().on('mouseover')`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-on) and [`panel.getHeader().getEl().on('mouseleave')`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-on) method on [`afterrender`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.grid.Panel.html#event-afterrender) event of `grid`.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2apa)**, I have created a demo using your code. You can check here how it is working. Hope this will help you or guide you to solve your problem or achieve your requirement.

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'problemListStoreDetails',
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data: [{
        value1: 'Value 1',
        value2: "Active",
        value3: "11/2006"
    }, {
        value1: 'Value2',
        value2: "Inactive",
        value3: "1/1/1998"
    }, {
        value1: 'Value3',
        value2: "Active",
        value3: "5/2017"
    }, {
        value1: 'Value4',
        value2: "pending",
        value3: "11/2017"
    }, {
        value1: 'Value5',
        value2: "Historic",
        value3: "1/9/2000"
    }]
});
Ext.define('MyApp.MyClass', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.panel-details',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('problemListStoreDetails'),
    width: 300,
    columns: {
        defaults: {
            sortable: false,
            hideable: true,
            menuDisabled: true,
            draggable: false,
            style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            }
        },
        items: [{
            text: "Column1",
            dataIndex: 'value1',
            menuDisabled: true
        }, {
            text: "Column2",
            dataIndex: 'value2',
            menuDisabled: true,
            align: 'center'
        }, {
            text: 'Column3',
            dataIndex: 'value3',
            menuDisabled: true,
            align: 'center',
            flex: 1
        }]
    },
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (cmp) {
            var me = this,
                header = cmp.getHeader().getEl();
            //mouse enter event
            header.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                var targ = e.target.querySelector('i.x-custom-icons'),
                    classList = targ ? targ.classList : null;

                if (targ) {
                    switch (targ.getAttribute('index')) {
                    case "0":
                        classList.remove('fa-html5')
                        break;
                    case "1":
                        classList.remove('fa-wrench');
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        classList.remove('fa-bar-chart');
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        classList.remove('fa-align-justify');
                        break;
                    }
                    //I have used only one icon, only for demo you can use different icons on basis of your requirement.
                    classList.add('fa-check');
                    this.lastTarget = targ;
                }
            }, me);

            //mouseleave event
            header.on('mouseleave', function (e) {
                if (this.lastTarget) {
                    var targ = this.lastTarget,
                        classList = targ.classList;
                    //remvoe icon on mouse leave
                    classList.remove('fa-check');
                    switch (targ.getAttribute('index')) {
                    case "0":
                        classList.add('fa-html5')
                        break;
                    case "1":
                        classList.add('fa-wrench');
                        break;
                    case "2":
                        classList.add('fa-bar-chart');
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        classList.add('fa-align-justify');
                        break;
                    }
                    this.lastTarget = null;
                }
            }, me);
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Accordion Layout',
    autoHeight: true,
    fill: false,
    layout: {
        type: 'accordion',
        titleCollapse: false
    },
    bodyPadding: 10,
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'panel-details'
    },
    items: [{
        title: '<i index="0" class="fa fa-html5 x-custom-icons" ></i>'
    }, {
        title: '<i index="1" class="fa fa-wrench x-custom-icons" ></i>'
    }, {
        title: '<i  index="2" class="fa fa-bar-chart x-custom-icons" ></i>',
    }, {
        title: '<i  index="3" class="fa fa-align-justify x-custom-icons"></i>'
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```